# Pinch gesture to expand a UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

An application I'm working on requires a layout very similar to that of the Photos app on iPad. There's a grid of `UIView`s and the user should be able to pinch into a single one, and as they're pinching in, watch that view grow in size until it's full screen.

So far, I have set up a `UICollectionViewController` and a custom collection view cell. I added the pinch gesture recognizer to the custom cell. When the user pinches in, the cell grows in size.

The issue I am now having is that the cell isn't layering on top of all other cells as it expands. Rather, it is hiding under the cells loaded after it.

I was thinking that the solution may be that when the collection view controller recognizes the pinch gesture, it could hide the cell being pinched on. Then, create a new `UIView` that is a copy of the collection view cell, with the bounds equivalent to where the cell was placed. Then, this view can be the one that can be pinched, rotated, and panned. As soon as the user ends the gesture, the view would just animate back to the original cell position and then be set to `nil`.

However, I'm not sure if this is the optimal solution and maybe there's some easy way to ensure a certain cell is layered on top of all other cells in the collection view.

The code for a snippet of my current implementation of how I'm scaling the cell is shown below. This is the one that creates the issue of the cell hiding under later cells as it expands.

```
 @objc func scalePiece(_ gestureRecognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    guard gestureRecognizer.view != nil else { return 

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || 
       gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {

        gestureRecognizer.view?.transform = (gestureRecognizer.view?.transform.scaledBy(x: gestureRecognizer.scale, y: gestureRecognizer.scale))!

        gestureRecognizer.scale = 1.0

    }
}
```

Comment: I also use the copy-view approach for those situations. Even though it takes a little more effort (positioning, replicating the cell's appearance), it's cleaner implementation-wise, you don't mess with the actual cell and the collection view, plus you don't have to deal with layers if you add it when receiving the gesture.

Comment: Tried `bringSubviewToFront(_:)`? Requires a reference to the collection view itself... Not completely sure what the full implications would be.

Comment: perhaps using the Z index?

Comment: bringSubviewToFront does the job! Thanks Josh!

Comment: Well that wasn't really the question though, right? Your question was more about the *best practice*.

Comment: Yes, it was about the best practice preferably. I'm thinking about the performance differences between these solutions and it seems like bringSubviewToFront() seems to be the least computationally expensive.

Comment: adjusting the layer.zPosition so it increments to 1 when the gesture is on it and decrements to 0 when the gesture ends also is a really nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

One dirt-simple possibility to remedy the cell being behind others is to invoke `bringSubviewToFront(_:)` on the collection view, passing the cell.

**Caveat** however, I'm not sure that this is *optimal*: since you don't really own the cells/the collection view's hierarchy, generally speaking you shouldn't touch the subviews directly like this.

A closely-related possibility -- not as simple, but probably much more robust and thus preferable -- is to **customize the layout**. Since the collection view's `UICollectionViewLayout` object [can specify the `zIndex` of a particular cell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayoutattributes/1617768-zindex), you could reload the cell when the pinch gesture begins and update the Z index for just that cell.

Comment: In terms of best practices, should the gesture recognizer for the cell expansion be placed under the UICollectionViewController or in a custom collection view cell?

Comment: In this case it seems to me that it should go in the collection view itself. The disadvantage is that you have to figure out which cell was hit.